# How do i use google phonenumber lib in ionic project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I am currently working on ionic project and i would like to integrate Google phone number lib into my project. Here is the [GitHub url](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber). I also found out [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-libphonenumber) repository.

**Want to do**

- backend api will give me ph number with its country code . eg +6599091151
- In client side(ionic), i want to check this phone number in user contacts or not.Since phone numbers inside phone contact can vary in bunch different form. Sometime people put country code but sometimes don't.

Library i found out which is best suited for my situation is [google phonenumber lib](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)

**Problem**

- I found out Google phonenumber lib have quite a bunch of dependencies and i am not even able to run demo app.
- So I found out NPM version of the same library. But nodejs library are not able run like a normal .js file and as i search thru a bit , i found browsify plugin which is able to make nodejs module run in angularjs code .

If there is an easy step to follow to get google-phonenumber lib working easily, please point me out or at least show me how this can be done.

Comment: Please share some code, tell us about the "difficulties" you are facing. This question is too vague to answer.

Comment: @AbhyuditJain , i had updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do in my projects:

```
npm install --save google-libphonenumber
```

Then code:

```
const phoneUtil = require('google-libphonenumber').PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();


const isValidPhoneNumberAndCountryCode = function (phone, country_code) {
    const regionCode = phoneUtil.getRegionCodeForCountryCode(country_code);
    if (regionCode.toUpperCase() === "ZZ") {
        return false;
    }

    console.log("REGION CODE: ", regionCode);

    const phoneNumber = phoneUtil.parse(phone, regionCode);

    console.log("IS PHONE VALID: ", phoneUtil.isValidNumber(phoneNumber));
    console.log("PHONE NUMBER TYPE: ", phoneUtil.getNumberType(phoneNumber));

    // You can go through the library source to find what the codes are.
    // Allow only mobile and fixed_line_or_mobile to pass
    return phoneUtil.isValidNumber(phoneNumber) && (phoneUtil.getNumberType(phoneNumber) === 0 || phoneUtil.getNumberType(phoneNumber) === 1 || phoneUtil.getNumberType(phoneNumber) === 2);
};
```

This is how I validate my phone numbers. I expect a country code and phone number.

NOTE: Some places like American Samoa have a 4 digit country code. That is misleading. The country code is 1 and the other 3 digits you have to append before the phone number.

Comment: do i need to use **browsify** ?